# Event sourcing with Kafka and topic per entity type, what happens with foreign keys?

Tags: apache-kafka, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I'm trying to design an event sourced system with Kafka. Let's say we have a very simple event sourced application consisting of four aggregate roots: users, categories, products and purchases.

Following some guidance from [confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/), I've created 4 topics (and let's assume 1 partition per topic for simplicity), one per each aggregate:

- One topic for users
- One topic for categories
- One topic for products
- One topic for purchases

My projection is a PostgresSQL projection, which reads events from Kafka, and then turns each event into an SQL query (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE depending on the type of event).

The problem is that the database model is approximately something like this:

[image]

Given that event order is not guaranteed between topics, if I try to add a product to the database without its category, I will most likely receive a ForeignKey error from the database. Likewise, if I try to add a purchase without the user or the product having been processed yet, I will most likely receive another ForeignKey error.

What partitioning options do I have to workaround this foreign key issue in the read model, and allow my system to grow with more entities and more events without having to rely on putting everything into a single topic to avoid foreign key problems?

Something that occurred to me is that, while I could process users and products independently without clashes, I would still need to do something with the purchases (delaying somehow the processing of events on that topic till ensuring that the user and the product exist in the database).

Comment: Do you have to apply some validation before an event is generated? Do you rely on your db for that?

Comment: @rascio I have 2 models, a command model used for validations (which relies on SQL and gets updated in the same transaction as the event store) and the read model. I don't rely on the read model for validation.

Comment: I wonder what you use as the aggregate state when executing commands. Do you read from Postgres? It's stale by definition.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I read from a synchronous source of truth for the aggregate state which is guaranteed to not be stale.

Comment: I wonder how the truth source could be guaranteed not stale if the source of truth in Event Sourcing is events and you aren't reading them. If the state stored in Postgres is your source of truth, why are you calling it Event Sourcing?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Postgres is my projection/readmodel. I have another DB specifically tailored for events (which is mostly for writes/aggregate restitution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your target data model uses foreign keys, you're fundamentally going to have to delay successful inserts until the constraints can be met.

Conceivably, to do this (assuming that you're running the consuming streams concurrently), is to have the query retry on failure until it succeeds, though this will typically entail preventing further messages from the affected partition from being processed.  It also, depending on what the meanings of events are (e.g. if it's possible for a delete to occur or certain columns to be updated), potentially opens various deadlocks and data races arising from non-deterministic order of consumption.

Considering that the purpose of things like foreign key constraints is to validate and reject writes, they generally don't have much purpose in a read-model, where the writes have already been validated by the write-model: an event associating a product with a category should be considered incontrovertible proof that the product and category each exist, regardless of the state of the read-model.  This suggests at least one of: i) removing the foreign key constraints from the read-model, ii) having the projection create minimal records in the read-model in order to allow the foreign key to validate, iii) having some "pending" tables for records which you know exist but aren't yet complete (your projection might then check the pending table to see if an update could be what's needed to complete a pending record), or iv) rethinking your aggregates.

Comment: A broader theme here is that a fair portion of CQRS/ES is raising the sorts of things that a database can typically do for you out of the infrastructure and into the application.